# Problem after transferred a solution from SharePoint Foundation to SharePoint Server

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

After I transferred my solution from SharePoint Foundation to the production SharePoint Server some features don't work from My project. I am getting error when I try to add another web part or a list to the server after my project web part.

[image]

Error log shows me this collision:

> 11-07-2012 09:10:49.11 w3wp.exe (0x1AF0)       0x08AC SharePoint
>   Foundation                Logging Correlation Data             xmnv
>   Medium              Name=Request
>   (POST:/?WikiPageMode=Edit&InitialTabId=Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab&VisibilityContext=WSSWikiPage)
>   c5debe0f-dcd8-4b88-a064-6c3a67616edc 11-07-2012 09:10:49.55 w3wp.exe
>   (0x1AF0)       0x08AC SharePoint Foundation                Logging
>   Correlation Data             xmnv                Medium
>   Site=/   c5debe0f-dcd8-4b88-a064-6c3a67616edc 11-07-2012 09:10:49.55
>   w3wp.exe (0x1AF0)       0x08AC SharePoint Foundation
>   Monitoring         b4ly       High                Leaving Monitored
>   Scope (PostResolveRequestCacheHandler). Execution
>   Time=434,578975819552     c5debe0f-dcd8-4b88-a064-6c3a67616edc
>   11-07-2012 09:10:49.65 w3wp.exe (0x1AF0)       0x08AC SharePoint
>   Foundation                General               90hv      Unexpected
>   Detected use of SPRequest for previously closed SPWeb object.  Please
>   close SPWeb objects when you are done with all objects obtained from
>   them, but not before.  Stack trace:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.SharePointClientJs_Register(Page
>   page)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterForControl(Control
>   ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer,
>   Boolean loadAfterUI, String language)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterForControl(Control
>   ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer,
>   Boolean loadAfterUI, String language)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.Register(Page page, String
>   name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer, Boolean loadAfterUI, String
>   language, String uiVersion)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb)     at
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)               c5debe0f-dcd8-4b88-a064-6c3a67616edc
>   11-07-2012 09:10:49.69 w3wp.exe (0x1AF0)       0x08AC SharePoint
>   Foundation                Monitoring         b4ly       High
>   Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData#1). Execution
>   Time=15,6924972307933             c5debe0f-dcd8-4b88-a064-6c3a67616edc
>   11-07-2012 09:10:49.70 w3wp.exe (0x1AF0)       0x08AC SharePoint
>   Foundation                General               837l        Exception 
>   An unhandled exception occured. Watson will be invoked.
>   c5debe0f-dcd8-4b88-a064-6c3a67616edc 11-07-2012 09:10:49.70 w3wp.exe
>   (0x1AF0)       0x08AC SharePoint Foundation                Unified
>   Logging Service                c91s                Monitorable
>   Watson bucket parameters: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 4,
>   ULSException14, 269cd32d "sharepoint foundation", 0e00178d
>   "14.0.6029.0", e266f8d6 "stswel.dll", 0e00178d "14.0.6029.0", 4db90a0b
>   "thu apr 28 08:32:43 2011", MISSING, 00142dc9 "00142dc9", c0000005
>   "c0000005", 3833376c "837l"
>   c5debe0f-dcd8-4b88-a064-6c3a67616edc 11-07-2012 09:10:49.70 w3wp.exe
>   (0x1AF0)       0x08AC SharePoint Foundation                General
>   8e2s      Medium                Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More
>   information: 0x80020009   c5debe0f-dcd8-4b88-a064-6c3a67616edc
>   11-07-2012 09:10:49.70 w3wp.exe (0x1AF0)       0x08AC SharePoint
>   Foundation                Web Parts          tkqm     High
>   WebPartAdder_ItemCannotBeAddedULS
>   c5debe0f-dcd8-4b88-a064-6c3a67616edc 11-07-2012 09:10:49.72 w3wp.exe
>   (0x1AF0)       0x08AC SharePoint Foundation                Runtime
>   tkau       Unexpected
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Attempted to use an
>   object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102
>   (STG_E_REVERTED))    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetWebListPermMask(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetWebListPermMask(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName)   c5debe0f-dcd8-4b88-a064-6c3a67616edc
>   11-07-2012 09:10:49.83 w3wp.exe (0x1AF0)       0x08AC SharePoint
>   Foundation                Monitoring         b4ly       Medium
>   Leaving Monitored Scope (Request
>   (POST:/Rozliczenie.aspx?WikiPageMode=Edit&InitialTabId=Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab&VisibilityContext=WSSWikiPage)).
>   Execution Time=712,432725388283
>   c5debe0f-dcd8-4b88-a064-6c3a67616edc

Comment: I found this, but I don't geret what does it means. How to change `SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're **not** calling either

```
witryna.Dispose();
```

or do this

```
using(SPWeb witryna = SPContext.Current.Web)
{
// some code
}
```

Using 'using' will dispose the witryna when going out of using-clause, and you're not supposed to dispose objects created from SPContext. SharePoint takes care of that.